# django record update error

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

here's my form...

```
class PercentForm(forms.Form):
    percent = forms.IntegerField()
```

here's my view that uses this:

```
formx = PercentForm(request.POST or None)
if formx.is_valid():
                px = Pxxx.objects.get(id = user.id )
                pcx = formx.cleaned_data['percent']
                pc = (float(pcx / 10)
                px.percentage_instant = pc
                px.save()
```

pxxx model

```
percentage_instant = models.FloatField()
```

so say my input is 3 it should store as 0.3 but it stores as 0. why is that? where may the error be? I cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: Are you sure we're reading the same code?

Comment: Your edit cleared up the obvious thing. Now for the other...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `pcx` is an integer then `pcx / 10` will still be an integer on 2.x. Perhaps you meant `float(pcx) / 10` or `pcx / 10.0`.